# DefinePlugin doesn't replace var when "process.env" is used on same line

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using `webpack.DefinePlugin` with a really simple config to set a client vs server var:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __CLIENT__: JSON.stringify(false),
})
```

When I run this over the following file, it only replaces one of the two uses of `__CLIENT__`:

```
export const CLIENT = __CLIENT__;
export const processEnv = __CLIENT__ ? null : process.env;

// === compiles to the following: ===>

export const CLIENT = false;
export const processEnv = __CLIENT__ ? null : process.env; // __CLIENT__ doesn't get replaced.
```

When I change the second line to have *anything* other than process.env, it works fine.

```
export const CLIENT = __CLIENT__;
export const processEnv = __CLIENT__ ? null : 'works!';

// === compiles to the following: ===>

export const CLIENT = false;
export const processEnv = false ? null : 'works!'; // __CLIENT__ gets replaced.
```

I can work around this problem pretty trivially by first saving `__CLIENT__` to some other variable like the following, but it makes me completely distrust `webpack.DefinePlugin` for future uses.

```
export const CLIENT = __CLIENT__;
export const processEnv = CLIENT ? null : process.env;

// === compiles to the following: ===>

export const CLIENT = false;
export const processEnv = false ? null : process.env; // Works, compiles fine.
```

Perhaps even stranger, it seems like `webpack.DefinePlugin` cares about the *value* I'm setting. This compile properly:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __CLIENT__: JSON.stringify(true), // Instead of false
})

...

// Same code as initial example:
export const CLIENT = __CLIENT__;
export const processEnv = __CLIENT__ ? null : process.env;

// === compiles to the following: ===>

export const CLIENT = true;
export const processEnv = true ? null : 0; // Works, compiles fine.
```

Why does `webpack.DefinePlugin` care what my replacement value is? Am I doing something wrong? Is there some other configuration I should change?